# Prevent words from breaking/wrapping mid-word in iOS email client

Tags: html, ios, css, email, zurb-ink

I am building markup for an HTML email, however I can't seem to find a solution to prevent a word from breaking mid-word like this in iOS email client:

[image]

HTML:

```
<table class="row">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="mail-title">
        <td class="wrapper last">
            <table class="twelve columns">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1 class="center">YOUR ORDER 101 HAS BEEN DISPATCHED</h1>
                    </td>
                    <td class="expander"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.mail-title h1 {
    font-size      : 18px;
    text-transform : uppercase;
    font-weight    : normal;
    word-wrap      : none;
    word-break     : break-all;
}
```

I am using the [Zurb Ink email framework](http://zurb.com/ink/), which is what the `wrapper`, `last` and `expander` classes are for.

I'#ve had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2259695/691505), which makes sense as Ink defaults to `break-word`, but this doesn't work on iOS mail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is specific to those implementing email templates with Zurb Ink. So, it appears this is default Ink styling. See here: https://github.com/zurb/ink/blob/master/css/ink.css#L71

I changed the declaration of `td` to be as below:

```
td {
    word-break      : normal;
    border-collapse : collapse !important;
}
```

Fixed.

Answer (score 10):

Add the following into your custom styles section of your template to override Ink's styling.

```css
td {
  word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: none;
  -moz-hyphens: none;
  hyphens: none;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete word instead of broken words. use `white-space:nowrap;` instead of `word-break : break-all;`

**CSS**

```
.mail-title h1 {
    font-size : 18px;
    text-transform : uppercase;
    font-weight : normal;
    word-wrap : none;
    white-space : no-wrap;
}
```

Comment: This helps, thanks. However what I need is it to wrap but _not_ cut-off mid-word. So in the example above 'DISPATCHED' should fall down onto another line, however it should be the full word and not just 'PATCHED'. Is that possible?

Comment: white-space:no-wrap should take the word on the next line which is overflowing the width.

Comment: With or without the `-` in `no-wrap` this doesn't seem to work in the iOS email app.